# PHP: number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm getting the following error message in my PHP script;

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement
```

But here is the relevant code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect( $db_url, $db_user, $db_pwd, $db );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM problems WHERE mrn=?";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare( $con, $sql );
mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, 'i', $sent_mrn );
```

It points me to the last line there. Am I missing something really obvious? There is only one parameter in the SQL query and I'm binding only one variable! (I know some people will suggest I use PDO, but I gotta use mysqli at the moment)

Comment: What are you passing in `$sent_mrn`

Comment: Right above the first line is $sent_mrn = 123;

Answer (score 0):

When using procedural functions (as opposed to object-oriented), you must first call [`mysqli_stmt_init()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stmt-init.php) to get the statement object. Then you call `mysqli_prepare` with this statement as the first parameter, NOT the connection as you are currently doing. Also you don't need the return value of `mysqli_prepare` unless you're meticulously checking for error conditions. Its return value is NOT passed to `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`, but rather the statement returned from `mysqli_stmt_init()`.

Comment: I've never had to use mysqli_stmt_init() before with my code and it's worked - strange.

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = mysqli_connect( $db_url, $db_user, $db_pwd, $db );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM problems WHERE mrn=?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql); 
$stmt -> bind_param('i', $sent_mrn);
```

Give this a try.